# Understand what Ioctl do

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, arm, syscall

I looking in ida on arm linux binary . I can see there that there is ioctl call

`ioctl(fd,req,num)`.

fd is fd to /dev/module. ,req is some 4bytes and num is some number.

How can I understand what this ioctl call do?

What `req` number mean?

Where can I find the handle of this ioctl?

Comment: You should study a bit that syscall, in general ioctl is for access drivers, and is very dependent of the driver, in your case /dev/module, do a man ioctl and you will understand better how works, there is plenty of information about it, just google it

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the driver (either a separate binary or built-in into the kernel) which publishes this dev file entry, the code to handle the ioctl request will be in it.

Here’s an article with an example of ioctl handler:

https://opensourceforu.com/2011/08/io-control-in-linux/

String search for the file name may be the quickest way to do find the required binary/code area.